# How can shipping cost in checkout cart?

Tags: product, cart, shipping

I need display in checkout/cart in cart totals shipping, now i created table rate file csv, make import in Shipping Methods, other method is disable and save, when i send products in cart, i see total amount without shipping price, how can I show the shipping price in the cart total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a box in the shopping cart where you can enter your ZIP code and country to estimate shipping costs. If you use this, the shipping cost (and tax) is included in the cart.

Comment: possible change behavior of the cart? if possible let me know

Comment: Yes, you can programmatically calculate shipping for default address on product adding event

Comment: Great, but how? i found what can do with support this:$address = $quote->getShippingAddress(); $address->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); but not sure where i can place this code for modify cart

Comment: @John, i think you can modify the "estimate shipping" box, _prepareLayout method.